# SwiftUI HStack TextField alignment

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create two HStacks with a Text and a TextField.
Both Stacks are placed inside an VStack to place them vertically under each other.

The problem I have is the following:

On the screenshot below you can see that the last Textfield is slightly larger than the upper one. Properly because of the larger text field.

[image]

I want to have both Textfield the same size and are placed under each other on the same spot.

To be clear, the under last textfield need to be placed exactly under the upper one with the same width and height.

I don't know how to get this job done.
I have tried several things with .frame modifier, but seems not to work.

Has some any idea?

Here is the code for the HStacks

```
                HStack {
                Text("Voorfietskosten:")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.custom("Rubik-Light_Medium", size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))
                TextField("Voorfietskosten", value: $ccControler.amountBikingCosts, format: .currency(code: "EUR"))
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            HStack {
                Text("Tarief kwartier:")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.custom("Rubik-Light_Medium", size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))
                TextField("Tarief per kwartier", value: $ccControler.amountEachQuarterTime, format: .currency(code: "EUR"))
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Charcoal"))
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the text fields' widths fixed, and add a spacer in between the text and text field so that the `HStack` expands as far as it can in the middle, and that its contents don't "stick together".

Example:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Voorfietskosten:")
            // ...

        // spacer here!
        Spacer()

        TextField("Voorfietskosten", text: .constant("123"))
            // ...
            .frame(width: 200) // fix width here!
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)

    HStack {
        Text("Tarief kwartier:")
            .padding()
            // ...

        // spacer here!
        Spacer()

        TextField("Tarief per kwartier", text: .constant("123"))
            // ...
            .frame(width: 200) // fix width here!
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
}.background(.gray)
```

[image]

Also consider using [`LabeledContent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labeledcontent):

```
VStack {
    LabeledContent {
        TextField("Voorfietskosten", text: .constant("123"))
            // ...
            .frame(width: 200)
    } label: {
        Text("Voorfietskosten:")
            // ...
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)

    LabeledContent {
        TextField("Tarief per kwartier", text: .constant("123"))
            // ...
            .frame(width: 200)
    } label: {
        Text("Tarief kwartier:")
            // ...
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
}.background(.gray)
```